# What's the biggest .csv file you can import into a Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, csv

I'm trying to upload/import a 7 MB .csv file to Google Sheets without much luck.

What's the largest file size that you can import?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Taken from this Help article on Google Docs:](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37603)

Editor note: Some parts of the below data are obsolete, better to look at the above link.

**Updated - 7th Nov 2017**

> **File sizes**
>
> These are the documents, spreadsheets, and presentation sizes you can
> store in Google Drive.
>
> - **Documents**: Up to 1.02 million characters. If you convert a text document to Google Docs format, it can be up to 50 MB.
> - **Spreadsheets**: Up to 2 million cells for spreadsheets that are created in or converted to Google Sheets.
> - **Presentations**: Up to 100 MB for presentations converted to Google Slides.
> - **All other files**: Up to 5 TB.
>
> **Supported file types**
>
> These are the most common file types you can view in Google Drive:
>
> **General files**
>
> - Archive files (.ZIP, .RAR, tar, gzip)
> - Audio formats (MP3, MPEG, WAV, .ogg)
> - Image files (.JPEG, .PNG, .GIF, .BMP)
> - Markup/Code (.CSS, .HTML, .PHP, .C, .CPP, .H, .HPP, .JS)
> - Text files (.TXT)
> - Video files (WebM, .MPEG4, .3GPP, .MOV, .AVI, .MPEGPS, .WMV, .FLV, .ogg)
>
> **Adobe files**
>
> - Autodesk AutoCad (.DXF)
> - Illustrator (.AI)
> - Photoshop (.PSD)
> - Portable Document Format (.PDF)
> - PostScript (.EPS, .PS)
> - Scalable Vector Graphics (.SVG)
> - Tagged Image File Format (.TIFF) - best with RGB .TIFF images
> - TrueType (.TTF)
>
> **Microsoft files**
>
> - Excel (.XLS and .XLSX)
> - PowerPoint (.PPT and .PPTX)
> - Word (.DOC and .DOCX)
> - XML Paper Specification (.XPS)

So your file size doesn't seem to be an issue - maybe it is the number of columns and/or cells?

Answer (score 5):

As of July 2019, my own experimentation says that:

A csv file of ~ 300000 cells, ~ 80 MB, was imported properly.

A csv file of ~ 700000 cells, ~ 100 MB, was not allowed to be imported.

I wasn't able to find any official documentation on this feature, but the import dialog will properly inform you if the .csv is "too large".

Comment: As of March 2nd, 2023, the help article linked in the [accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/10828/88163) includes limit of CSV imports.