# Can Google Spreadsheets handle 10 million rows?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data file with 14 columns and 9,523,125 rows.

Can a Google Spreadsheet handle at least 9,523,125 rows?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange! This site does not accept requests for recommendations. We have a sister site that does, but your question needs to meet [certain guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). In particular, all questions must both define a goal or task to accomplish, and list some objective requirements. Please read the guidelines and improve your question accordingly, then you can repost your question on the Software Recommendations site.

Comment: Even if it can, how will you open it in browser :P

Comment: Related [What's the biggest .csv file you can import into a Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/10824/88163)

Answer (score 7):

This question is old, but because Google has updated their limits since the question was asked, I have updated my answer with the latest information.

Again for your cell count the answer is still: **NO**

UPDATED AS OF 6/21/2022

That said google has upped its cell limit to 10 million. I have tested this and it will load exactly 10 million cells into google sheets but no more.

As a reference at the time of this post the current limitations are:

[Source info @ gsuitetips.com](https://gsuitetips.com/tips/sheets/google-spreadsheet-limitations/#targetText=Google%20Spreadsheet%20limitations,-View&targetText=Up%20to%205%20million%20cells,Tabs%3A%20200%20sheets%20per%20workbook)

- Up to 10 million cells for spreadsheets that are created in or converted to Google Sheets
- 40,000 new rows at a time
- Maximum number of columns of 18,278 columns
- Number of Tabs: 200 sheets per workbook
- GoogleFinance formulas: 1,000 GoogleFinance formulas
- ImportRange formulas: 50 cross-workbook reference formulas
- ImportData, ImportHtml, ImportFeed, or ImportXml formulas: 50 functions for external data
- Maximum string length is 50,000 characters

*For the direct information on what is supported by google drive here is the* [Google Help Answer](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en).

The following are the maximum file sizes you can store in Google Drive:

**Documents**

> ​Up to 1.02 million characters. If you convert a text document to
> Google Docs format, it can be up to 50 MB.

**Spreadsheets**

> ​Up to 10 million cells or 18,278 columns (column ZZZ) for
> spreadsheets that are created in or converted to Google Sheets. Up to
> 10 million cells or 18,278 columns for spreadsheets imported from
> Microsoft Excel. The limits are the same for Excel and CSV imports.
> When you convert a document from Excel to Google Sheets, any cell with
> more than 50,000 characters will be removed in Sheets.

**Presentations**

> ​Up to 100 MB for presentations converted to Google Slides.

**Google Sites (new)**

> Up to 15,000,000 characters per page. Up to 40,000,000 characters per
> site. Up to 10,000 pages per site. Up to 15,000 images per site.

**All other files**

> ​Up to 5 TB.

**Supported file types**

*Any file type can be stored in Drive. These are the most common file types you can preview in Google Drive:*

**General files**

> Archive files (.ZIP, .RAR, tar, gzip) Audio formats (MP3, MPEG, WAV,
> .ogg, .opus) Image files (.JPEG, .PNG, .GIF, .BMP, .TIFF, .SVG)
> Markup/Code (.CSS, .HTML, .PHP, .C, .CPP, .H, .HPP, .JS, .java, .py)
> Text files (.TXT) Video files (WebM, .MPEG4, .3GPP, .MOV, .AVI,
> .MPEGPS, .WMV, .FLV, .ogg)

**Adobe files**

> Autodesk AutoCad (.DXF) Illustrator (.AI) Photoshop (.PSD) Portable
> Document Format (.PDF) PostScript (.EPS, .PS) Scalable Vector Graphics
> (.SVG) Tagged Image File Format (.TIFF) - best with RGB .TIFF images
> TrueType (.TTF)

**Microsoft files**

> Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) PowerPoint (.PPT and .PPTX) Word (.DOC and
> .DOCX) XML Paper Specification (.XPS) Password-protected Microsoft
> Office files

**Apple files**

> Editor files (.key, .numbers)

Comment: Perhaps you can add this reference to your answer: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I did add the reference. Do you mean some content from the 2nd reference? Mostly it just mirrors the other info. If I added quotes from the 2nd reference it would just be redundant.

Comment: As for the cell reference, this comes from Google...I think some of the info is outdated as well.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I have tested all the limitations for Google Sheets and the current info is reflected as accurate in my testing. The 5m cells, the 100mb limit and so on.

Comment: The limit of 50 funtions for external data is obsolete. I just created an spreadsheet with 100 importxml

Comment: @Rubén if you can find an official source of info I will update the post.

Comment: Looks like this answer is outdated now that Google has increased the limits once again.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks for the notice. I have updated the post to be current.