# Posting more than 2,000 lines from IFTTT to a Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, if-this-then-that

I have an IFTTT trigger set up whose action is to add a row to a Google Sheets. Once the spreadsheet reaches 2,000 rows, IFTTT creates a new document with the title: `Document Title (1)` instead of adding a new row to the original spreadsheet. I've manually added ~40,000 more rows to the original document, but IFTTT still adds them to the `Document Title (1)` document.

I'd like to have all the rows added to just one document.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The problem is it doesn't add rows past 2000 lines. I want one document not many documents.

Comment: This would seem to be a feature request / support question for the IFTTT folks.

Comment: I was trying to find IFTTT support, but their [help](https://ifttt.com/help) and [contact](https://ifttt.com/contact) pages are useless. They don't respond to tweets.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this is actually an issue on *Google*'s end. There is a limit of `400,000 cells`, ([source](http://gappstips.com/google-sheets/google-spreadsheet-limitations/)) or `2 million cells` (for the new Google Sheets) per spreadsheet. ([source](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/65635/can-google-spreadsheets-handle-10-million-rows/65788#65788)).

When *IFTTT* reaches this limit it makes a new spreadsheet.

One temporary way to get around this limit is by deleting the columns you don't need (for example columns E onwards). This decreases the number of cells you are using of your `400,000` / `2 million` limit. But this only helps until you reach the new limit of rows.

If your sheet is still an old version another possible solution is making  it a "new version sheet"

Once IFTTT decides to create a new spreadsheet all new data will be added to the new one, regardless of if you have added *'extra space'*